# How to check if a string contains a given substring?

Tags: inno-setup

I need to find out if string contains a given substring.

For example, if I'm looking for the substring `ABC` in a string like this:

```
S := 'ABC String';
```

I should get result True, whilst for the following string I should get result False:

```
S := 'DEF String';
```

How to check if a string contains a substring in InnoSetup ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Innosetup has a Pos() function that works exactly like Delphi's. See the Support Functions Reference at http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptfunctions

Comment: Or a direct [`Pos`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_pos.htm) function reference [+1].